# How to remove values in a Groovy map

Tags: groovy

Say I have this map

```
def map = [:]
map.put("us-east-1", ["vol-66c16ec2", "vol-654ce2c1", "vol-01234567"])
map.put("us-east-2", ["vol-12345678", "vol-87654321", "vol-abcdefgh"])
```

which results in...

```
{
  "us-east-1" : [
    "vol-66c16ec2", "vol-654ce2c1", "vol-01234567"
  ],
  "us-east-2" : [
    "vol-12345678", "vol-87654321", "vol-abcdefgh"
  ]
}
```

How can I iterate through the map so when value = "vol-abcdefgh" I want to remove that entry. So pseudo-code is...

```
for (it=iterate_through_map) {
  if (it == "vol-abcdefgh") {
     remove_entry(it)
  }
}
```

and the resulting map is now...

```
{
  "us-east-1" : [
    "vol-66c16ec2", "vol-654ce2c1", "vol-01234567"
  ],
  "us-east-2" : [
    "vol-12345678", "vol-87654321"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following (**edit:** updated with elegant improvement by [dmahapatro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2051952/dmahapatro)):

```
def target = 'vol-abcdefgh'

def map2 = map.collectEntries { k, v -> [k, v - target] }
```

I have confirmed that it works in a Jenkins pipeline (unlike the spread operator, `*`).

Comment: Or `map.collectEntries { k, v -> [k, v - target] }` :)

Comment: Also @Michael's approach results in a new Map instead of mutating the original one.

Comment: Very nice @dmahapatro ; I've updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Straight-forward would be something like

```
map.values()*.removeAll{ 'vol-abcdefgh' == it }
```

see [docs](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2015/09/groovy-goodness-removing-elements-from.html) for details on `removeAll()`

Comment: Hmmm, this works in a plain Groovy script, but not Groovy in a Jenkinsfile, so I'll ask the Jenkins community